C# forms app - 'Resources' does not contain a definition for
I'm not a C# programmer. Just trying to put together a small utility app. I've run into a problem that doesn't make sense.
I have added some resources in my solution:

and set their properties to content & copy always.
In the main forms app, I want to use the images:
pictureBox_Product.Image = Properties.Resources.airsmart_co2;

But this gives the above error and red squiggles below the airsmart_co2. I thought this was how this was supposed to work. But, I know next to nothing about this... A little help?!

The way to do this is basically the same for all desktop application projects like "Windows Forms", "WPF" and "WinUI".
Have you added a "Resource File" with "Add new item" menu? It has the "resx" extension and should be located / added in a new "Properties" subfolder of your project.

Then double click this resx file in the solution explorer and in the editor that opens choose your image in the "Add resource / Add existing file" dropdown. This will insert the chosen image automatically in the (newly created) "Recources" sub folder of your project.

Then in solution explorer for the png file try setting the build action to 'none' and the copy to output directory setting to "do not copy".

